# How do you say ' to be good at something' in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase

How do you say 'to be good at something' in German?

> 1. Meine Mutter ist sehr gut dazu, dass sie das Haus sauber hält.
>      *My mother is very good at keeping the house clean.*
> 2. Ich bin sehr gut im Lernen (von) der deutschen Sprache.
>      *I am very good at studying the german language.*

Comment: *"Meine Mutter ist sehr gut dazu, "* would be translated as *"My mother is a good tool to, "*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1) Meine Mutter ist sehr gut darin, das Haus sauber zu halten.
>   2) Ich bin sehr gut im Lernen der deutschen Sprache.

There's a comma after „darin”, but you don't need a comma after „im”.

That's the exact translation, but normally you don't say that in German often.
We rather use something like this:

> 1) Meine Mutter hält das Haus sehr gut sauber.
>   (My mother keeps the house cleaned very well.) <-- not sure if this is correct :P
>
> 2) Ich lerne die deutsche Sprache sehr schnell.
>   (I learn the german language very fast.)

The use of "sehr gut" is not always the best. If you are learning good, it means fast I guess.

Comment: I disagree on that you don't normally say that. You do with simpler syntactic structures: "Sie ist gut in Mathe", "Er ist gut im Fußball", "Er ist gut darin, anderer Leute Mimik zu lesen".

Comment: @elena: IMO more than "gut sei in" we use "kann gut": *"er kann gut Fußball spielen"*, *"Mein Vater kann gut kochen"*, or we simply use "gut" as an adverb: *"Er spielt gut Fuball"*.

Comment: @Takkat We say **both**: "Sie *ist gut in* Mathe, aber *kann* nicht kochen." is fine. Though, "Sie kann Mathe, aber ist nicht gut im Kochen" might be a little odd.

Comment: Yeah sure, it depends much on the context whatever we prefer to use. With talent from school we indeed hear "gut sein" very often. This may come from the grades *"Er ist "gut" in Mathe"* where *"in"* then refers to the class.

Comment: @Takkat So essentially the form is *gut in + Dat.*?

Comment: @SkeletonBow: yeah that's it.

Answer (score 2):

A often used term is

> ein Talent für etwas haben

For example:

> Ich habe ein Talent dafür Deutsch zu lernen.